# ExtJS Filters Feature Error

Tags: extjs, filter

I am a novice in ExtJS and I am trying to include filters in ExTJS grid but I am getting an error like failed loading file "feature.filters". Below is my function for creating Grid and I am invoking this function from another HTML page.

```
function ExtJSGrid(tableId,headerInfo,data){

Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true});
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', 'http://vmxplambardi:19086/teamworks/script/extjs/examples/ux');
Ext.require([
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature',
    'Ext.toolbar.Paging'
]);


var tableId=tableId+"-div";
var fields=[],columns=[],dataIndex='cell';
var filters = {
        ftype: 'filters',
        local:true,
       filters: [{
            type: 'string',
            dataIndex: 'cell1'
        }, {
             type: 'string',
            dataIndex: 'cell2'
        }, {
             type: 'string',
            dataIndex: 'cell3'
        }]
    };

document.getElementById(tableId).innerHTML='';
for(var i=1;i<=headerInfo.length;i++)
{

var cellObj={},columnObj={};

cellObj.name=dataIndex+i;

fields.push(cellObj);

columnObj.text=headerInfo[i-1];

columnObj.dataIndex=dataIndex+i;

columns.push(columnObj);
}

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {

        fields:fields,

         data: data

    });

var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {

        store: store, 
        columns:columns,
    width:'100%',
    forceFit:true,
    features: [filters],
        renderTo: tableId

        });
}
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has no block level scope, so variables defined in the for loop are actually defined at the top of the function (hoisted) and survive the loops. So you are always overwrite the vars.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working like this:

```
var filters = {
    ftype: 'filters',
    // encode and local configuration options defined previously for easier reuse
    encode: false, // json encode the filter query
    local: true,   // defaults to false (remote filtering)

    // Filters are most naturally placed in the column definition, but can also be
    // added here.
    filters: [
        {
            type: 'boolean',
            dataIndex: 'visible' //Just an example
        }
    ]
};

var myFilterGrid = new Ext.create('Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel', {
    title: 'someTitle',
    selType: 'cellmodel',
    store: myStore,
    columns:[
        {
            header: "Column1",
            width: 90,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'INDEX1',
            filterable: true,  //<---
            filter:{           //<---
                type:'string'  
            }
        },
        ....
        {
            header: "Another Column",
            width: 85,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'INDEX2'
        }],
    features: [filters]  //<---
  });
```

And be sure to include

```
'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature'
```

Hope this helps!